# SharePoint 2013 Client-Side Custom Javascript Search Box with ability to populate results into an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

Scenario:

- Client would like improvements to their SharePoint 2013 "Search Engine"
- "Search engine" was orignally a more flashy key filter search, inputted into a script editor onto individual SharePoint 2013 lists.
- Client has requested the search engine to be on a blank site page with the ability to search entire site collection.
- Once results are retrieved client would like the results to populate into an HTML table located right below the search engine.
  Issue:
- Before I would restructure the URL upon onclick to filter what the client would see in a list however I understand that is no longer the case.

Question: Is there anyway to get those list items and display them into an HTML table upon an onclick event? In past projects I have made static XML, CamlQuerys, and AJAX calls to populate cells within a HTML table on load, however I have never made something like this on the client side of SharePoint 2013.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! My previous code has been included below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
<div class="hero-image">
<h1 style="color:black; font:46px castellar; text-shadow: 5px -5px #999999;"><strong>Transaction Retrieval</strong></h1>
</body>
</head>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search() {
        var st = document.getElementById("Searchtxt").value;
        var cd = document.getElementById("coldropdown").value;
        var url = "";

        if (st != "") {
            if (cd == "Employee ID" || cd == "Document ID" || cd == "Cycle Number" || cd == "Type of Transaction") {

                url = "FilterField1=" + cd + "&FilterValue1=" + st;
                window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
                    }
        else {
            return false;
        }  
  }
    function Clear() {  
      window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx";
    }
</script>


<p style="color:black; font:15px georgia;">Search Field:<select id="coldropdown" style="border-radius: 5px; border-color: black;"</p>
<option value="EmployeeID">Employee ID</option>
<option value="DocumentID">Document ID</option>
<option value="CycleNumber">Cycle Number</option>
<option value="TypeofTransaction">Type of Transaction</option>
</select>
<p style="color:black; font:15px georgia;">Search text: <input id="Searchtxt" type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; border-color: black;"</p>
<br>
<br>
<input id="btnSearch" onclick="return Search();" type="button" style=" background-color:Green; color:White; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 6px; box-shadow: 0 14px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 17px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)" value="Search"/>

<input id="btnClear" onclick="return Clear();" type="button" style=" background-color:Red; color:White; border-radius: 6px; font-size: 12px; box-shadow: 0 14px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 17px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)"   value="Clear"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Result Table</h2>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee ID</th>
      <th>Document ID</th>
      <th>Cycle Number</th>
      <th>Type of Transaction</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

          </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>


         </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image how the build out looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTlhE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint has a rich [REST-based API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview) that can be executed from Ajax in JavaScript.  Including [specific API'S for Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis).

To call the API and render it on the page dynamically, I would suggest utilizing a JavaScript framework to make things a little easier.  jQuery has helper methods for making the Ajax call, and helping you to manipulate the DOM to render your table, but you could probably make it more feature rich with paging and refiners and stuff by using Angular or ReactJS frameworks.  [Here is a good tutorial that shows you how to do it with jQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-from-javascript/).

Now, with all of that said, you may be able to get what you want without custom code by using the [Search Webparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint#how-the-content-search-web-part-works), including the [Search Box webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-search-box-web-part), the [Search Results Webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-search-results-web-part), and [Search Refinement webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-refinement-web-part).

Comment: I will give the REST API a look, and keep this updated :)

Comment: The implementation of REST API worked awesome and I was able to render list items onto a datatable, do you happen to know if it is possible to filter a REST API search off of another variable? in this case it would be "st" in my code. When the user types in what they want to search I would like it to filter off of what is in that search box.

Comment: Sure, when you use the REST search API, you include a `queryText` parameter in your URL, no reason you couldn't concatenate a JavaScript variable into that.  Likewise, if you're only looking in a list, concatenate it into the `$filter` param.

Comment: Would it be the same case if I was trying to draw data from multiple lists onto that one data table?

Comment: To query more than one list at a time, you'll definitely need to use the [search endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis) but yes, you can build your parameters with JavaScript variables.